# How do I stop a batch file that was run using child_process.exec() in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, batch-file

I found how to start the batch file that I want to run using the following code:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec('test.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
    });
```

However, I do not know hot to stop the batch file after it has been run with child_process.exec

I have read that I can use process.kill() or issue a command using SIGINT but I haven't had success in implementing it.

I want to be able to start the file using an express app.get /start and stop it with /stop separately.

Here is the full code I have so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const child_process = require('child_process');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
    child_process.exec('test.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
    });
    res.status(200).send(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

app.get('/stop', (req, res) => {
    child_process.exec('SIGINT', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
    });
    res.status(200).send(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Hello from the server!');
});
```

Edit: the batch file runs a minecraft server jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used spawn and directly started the jar file instead of using child_exec to run the batch file and it fixed my issue. Here is my code now:

```
const express = require('express');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const kill  = require('tree-kill');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let minecraftServerProcess;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
    minecraftServerProcess = spawn('java', [
        '-Xmx8192M',
        '-Xms8192M',
        '-jar',
        'mcserver.jar',
        'nogui'
    ]);

    function log(data) {
        process.stdout.write(data.toString());
    }
    minecraftServerProcess.stdout.on('data', log);
    minecraftServerProcess.stderr.on('data', log);

    res.status(200).send(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

app.get('/stop', (req, res) => {
    kill(minecraftServerProcess.pid);
    res.status(200).send(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Hello from the server!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const express = require('express');
const child_process = require('child_process');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let process;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
    process = child_process.exec('test.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
    });
    res.status(200).send(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

app.get('/stop', (req, res) => {
    process.kill()
    res.status(200).send(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Hello from the server!');
});
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal

Comment: I think this would work normally but I think it isn't working because I'm running a minecraft server using the batch file.

Comment: I would suggest not naming the variable process since that's already a global variable.

Comment: What karizma said and, if the process is running in background, you can write another bat file to find the Minecraft server process and kill it